# Значения в поле $img1 написано [BLOB - 21B]

Tags: php, mysql

```
$uploaddir  = 'Z:/home/localhost/www/img/upload/';
$apend      = date('YmdHis') . rand(100, 1000) . '.jpg';
$uploadfile = "$uploaddir$apend";

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img4']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "Файл 4
загружен.<br> ";
} else {
    echo "Файл
4 не загружен, верьнитель и
попробуйте еще раз";
}
```

Запись в MySQL

```
$result = mysql_query(" INSERT INTO news (namen,news,img1,user,moderate) VALUES ('$namen','$news','$apend','$user','0')") or die('ошибка бд');
```

В MySQL вместо значения в поле $img1 написано [BLOB - 21B]. Что это значит?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смените тип поля img1 с INT на TEXT